# SWIFT_MySQL fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift

I am running a simple app using SWIFT that pulls data from a remote MySQL server and I am receiving the following error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   import UIKit

ViewController Class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        processJSONData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func processJSONData(){

        let urlPath = "http://dubaisinan.host22.com/service1.php"

        let url : NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url,completionHandler: {(data, respose, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                println(error)
            }
            else {
                //println (data)

                let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
                print(jsonResult)
            }

        })
        task.resume()
    }
}

//service1.php:

    <?php // Create connection 
    $con=mysqli_connect("host_name","user_name","password","database_name");
    // Check connection 
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    { 
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
    } 
    // This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Locations' 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Countries";
    // Check if there are results 
    if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) 
    { 
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one 
    // to hold the data 
    $resultArray = array(); 
    $tempArray = array(); 
    // Loop through each row in the result set 
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) 
    { 
    // Add each row into our results array 
    $tempArray = $row; 
    array_push($resultArray, $tempArray); 
    } 
    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results 
    echo json_encode($resultArray); 
    } 
    // Close connections 
    mysqli_close($con); 
    ?>
```

**Does anyone see what is causing this error?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, this is why you shouldn't send error as nil.

```
var parseError: NSError?
let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &parseError);
println(parseError)
```

prints out the error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Garbage at end.) UserInfo=0x7feba8c533c0 {NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}

the JSON parse fails, lets see why:

```
let response = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
println(response)
```

you are printing not only json, you are printing also script

```
Optional(
[{"Country":"UAE","Capital":"Abu Dhabi"},{"Country":"Iraq","Capital":"Baghdad"}]
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
)
```

you should avoid printing hosting24 analytics scripts.
to avoid that (btw this is against hosting24 policy)
add after `mysqli_close($con);` the line `exit();` it will avoid from them printing out analytics script.

finally:

```
if error != nil {
    println(error)
}
else {
    var parseError: NSError?
    let result:AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &parseError);

    if(parseError == nil){

        if let dictResult = result as? NSArray{
            println(dictResult[0]["Capital"]);
            //The label does not show any data in the following????
            self.countryLabel.text = dictResult[1]["Country"] as? String
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I have added the exit() as suggested; The fatal error disappeared and the output was just (lldb) without the JSON file in addition to several thread comments. One of them said:  Swift dynamic cast failed. Any further help please?

Comment: let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &parseError);
                println(jsonResult)

works fine to me

Comment: Please clarify this part: error: &parseError... What about the return value: as NSDictionary? Kindly rewrite the whole line again. Many thanks.

Comment: @user2778855 welcome, just press the V button near my answer :)

Comment: Dear Daniel. One more request pls. When I print the country using println(dictResult[0]["Country"]) the result appears in the console output but when I try to insert the same value in a label using 
                 self.countryLabel.text = dictResult[1]["Country"] as? String the string will be empty in the label. Any clue please?

Comment: replace the as? String  with as! String, and don't forget to mark my question as the correct one, by pressing the V left to it

Comment: Replacing the as? String with as! String causes a syntax error that says expected type after 'as'. Your answer has been marked as the correct one, thank you.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Your feedback is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: hey, your welcome :) I'll help you no problem, just having some stuff at work

Comment: Using Xcode 6.1.1 with default SWIFT version. I need to check this.

Comment: Even if I use a debugging code like  self.countryLabel.text = "test" inside dataTaskWithURL method, I do not see any data in the label. If I move this statement outside then it works!!!!

Comment: I have updated the code. If I enter debugging code like self.capitalLabel.text = "something" outside the dataTaskWithURL method,  'something' shows in the label. If I move it inside, I do not see anything in the label.